# HTML <option> Tag . how to select a value?

Tags: html

Can any one help me with this..

i have an option box like this

```
<select name="facility_info_input[facility_type_id]" id="facility_type_id">
    <option value=1 >Room</option>
    <option value=2 >Equipment</option>
</select>
```

i want to select one of the above options automatically according to the variable  value(before user filling/updating the form the option should be already selected),
As an example i have a data variable(read from the database) and its value is 1 /2 , if its 1 can this "Room" option automatically selected, 
I have been trying to use selected="selected" attribute, but still I couldn't figure it out how to use it,is their a any other way?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Are you dynamically generating the HTML, e.g. PHP, ASP, etc.?

Comment: You should read the site FAQ. Of your eight questions you have received at least one correct answer. You should mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `selected="selected"` to the option you want selected by default. I am assuming you are doing this server side.

```
<select name="facility_info_input[facility_type_id]" id="facility_type_id">
    <option value="1" >Room</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2" >Equipment</option>
</select>
```

Also, you need to enclose your attributes in quotation marks. This may be why your code wasn't working.

```
<option value="1" /> //good
<option value=1 /> //bad
```

Comment: Thanks , the problem is there is no a default selected value, it should be according to  a variable,is the variable is set to  1 then 1st options should be shown and else the other option

Comment: What variable? Where is this variable? Server-side? Client-side?

Comment: thanks mrtsherman, the variable is in the data base, and its read before generating this form. its from server side.